# Twitter bootstrap json forms arrangement

Tags: html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to create forms with json schema using various libraries like json form by Josh factory and alpaca and so far I can produce the forms I want. However, the forms are all arranged in a vertical manner and one cannot easily change where the individual form fields are rendered.

I have tried alpaca templates to arrange my form fields but does not work for some fields like textarea.

Is there a library in bootstrap that I can use to generate forms from json and have them styled and arranged via bootstrap css?.

Comment: Write your own - its as simple as parsing the json and determining the input types and building the forms. I do it by having a series of "buildInput" functions that create a string representation of the form input html and when complete - passing that into the html of the form so that the DOM is modified only once.

Comment: Definitely a good thought since the forms are somewhat complex. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the strength of both libraries? Bootstrap rocks at laying out responsive grids & alpaca is awesome at turning JSON into forms.

Knock up a bootstrap layout and use Alpaca's layout binding abilities to set where the fields should be rendered.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CustomFormLayout").alpaca({
      "data": {
          "Picture": "http://www.alpacajs.org/assets/themes/dbyll/images/alpaca-icon.png"
        },
        "schema": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Love": {
                    "required": true,
                    "enum": ["I like goat", "I like lama", "I like alpaca"]
                },
                "LoveFactor": {
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "number",
                    "minimum": 1,
                    "maximum": 10
                },
                "Picture": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "dependencies": {
                "LoveFactor": ["Love"]
            }
        },
        "options": {
            "type": "object",
            "fields": {
                "Love": {
                    "type": "select",
                    "label": "Which animal do you love?",
                    "noneLabel": "-- Please Select an Animal --",
                    "removeDefaultNone": false
                },
                "LoveFactor": {
                    "label": "How much love does this animal get?",
                },
                "Picture": {
                  "type": "image",
                    "view": "bootstrap-display"
                }
                
            }
        },
        "view": {
            "parent": "bootstrap-create",
            "layout": {
                "template": `
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class ="col-xs-12">
                            <div data-alpaca-layout-binding='Love' class ='col-xs-6'></div>
                            <div data-alpaca-layout-binding='LoveFactor' class ='col-xs-6'></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-xs-12">
                            <div data-alpaca-layout-binding='Picture' class ='col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-5'></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `
            }
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.10/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.cloudcms.com/alpaca/1.5.23/bootstrap/alpaca.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://code.cloudcms.com/alpaca/1.5.23/bootstrap/alpaca.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="CustomFormLayout">

</div>
```